# Formatting a 2D Array to Have the Structure of an Addition Problem

Tags: java, arrays, 2d

I'm trying to do a program that involves reading in lines from a .txt file, and adds them together by converting them into int[] arrays of size 25. I decided to take the 2D array approach (which is already stepping out of "what we've learned" in this class) to bring multiple arrays together in an addition sense.

[image: Now here's what our professor wants us to get at.] The above image is how my professor describes the adding. We're appending ints found in a string line to the end of arrays with 25 zeroes. For instance, if one line of the .txt file reads "204 435 45", then we'd return it as such:

0000000000000000000000204

0000000000000000000000435

0000000000000000000000045

Then later on, we'd do the "elementary arithmetic" as mentioned in the photo link. Now here's what I got so far:

```
//This is the total overall size of the arrays (with all the zeroes)
public static final int ARRSIZE = 25;

//This is the majority of numbers to add on the biggest line in the .txt file
//This is kind of irrelevant here, but it means we'll always an 8 long array of arrays
public static final int MAXFACTONALINE = 8;

public static void breakTwo(String line)
{
   //Changed the value of the parameter for testing purposes
   line = "204 435 45";
   int[][] factors = new int[MAXFACTONALINE][25];
   //int[] nums = new int[ARRSIZE];
   int determine = 0;
   boolean isSpace = false;
   for(int i = 0; i < line.length(); i++)
   {
      String breakdown = line.substring(line.length() - 1 - i, line.length() - i);
      if(breakdown.equals(" "))
      {
         isSpace = true;
         determine++;
      }

      if(breakdown.equals(""))
         break;

      if(!isSpace)
      {
         int temp = Integer.parseInt(breakdown);
         factors[determine][factors.length - i] = temp;
      }

      isSpace = false;
      i = 0;
   }

   //To do: Implement another method to carry on with the above processing
}
```

What I'm aiming to do here is break those three numbers apart (since they're separated by whitespace) and put them in their own arrays, exactly like the 3 arrays I typed out above.

My output typically puts the numbers gained at random indexes, and I don't really have a good idea on how to keep hold of where they go. Could someone please help me identify how to keep them all on the right side like demonstrated above in the example? Thanks so much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can utilize the built in function `split(String regex)` to split apart the line for you. Since you know it'll always be white space, `line.split(" ")` will return an array of {"204", "435", "45"}.

After which, calculate the length of the string and concatenate it with a string that only contains `25 - number.length` leading 0's.

```
    public static void breakTwo(String line)
    {
       String [] numbers = line.split(" ");
       String [] zeros = new String[numbers.length];


       for (int i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++) {
           zeros[i] = "0";
           for (int j = 0; j < ARRSIZE - numbers[i].length() - 1; j++) {
               zeros[i] += "0";
           }
           zeros[i] += numbers[i];
           System.out.println(zeros[i]);
       }
    }
```

The output for `breakTwo("204 435 45")` is

```
0000000000000000000000204
0000000000000000000000435
0000000000000000000000045
```